# Emacs: how to find that at least one windows was vertically split

Tags: emacs, elisp

I don't know, how to write a function like this in elisp:

```
if(any window was split vertically)
    return t;
else
    return nil;

true:

|----------|     |----------|----------|
|          |     |          |          |
|          |     |          |          |
|----------|     |----------|----------|

false:

|--------|     |--------|-------|
|        |     |        |       |
|        |     |        |       |
|--------|     |        |-------|
|        |     |        |       |
|        |     |        |       |
|--------|     |--------|-------|
```

I found, that there is `window-list` function, that returns a list of all the windows. So, the algorithm should be like this:

```
(setq windows (window-list))
dolist(windows)
{
    if($_->is_vertically_split())
    {
        return nil;
    }
}

return t;
```

How can I determine, that this window is vertically split? It's height shouldn't be 100%.

### Update

Using @lawlist answer I wrote the following, but it doesn't work (always returns nil):

```
(defun no-window-is-vertically-split ()
  (let (windows (window-list)
                (result nil))
    (dolist (w windows)
      (when (or
             (window-in-direction 'above w)
             (window-in-direction 'below w))
             (setq result t)))
   result))


(no-window-is-vertically-split)
```

Is it possible to break the dolist loop and just return the value, when 1-st split window is found?

Comment: Be aware that `window-list` gives you a list of the windows for *only one frame*. That's apparently what want here, but just know that it does not cover all windows. To iterate over windows generally, use function **`walk-windows`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any of these to test whether there is a window above, below, left or right:

```
(window-in-direction 'above)
```

or

```
(window-in-direction 'below)
```

or

```
(window-in-direction 'left)
```

or

```
(window-in-direction 'right)
```

And here is an example using conditions -- just replace `[... do something]` with your preferred action:

```
(cond
  ((window-in-direction 'above)
    [... do something])
  ((window-in-direction 'below)
    [... do something])
  ((window-in-direction 'left)
    [... do something])
  ((window-in-direction 'right)
    [... do something]))
```

To test whether there is only one window, the following is useful:

```
(one-window-p t)
```

Here is a test similar to the call of the question, which is based upon the the test being performed from the selected window:

```
(if
    (or
      (window-in-direction 'above)
      (window-in-direction 'below))
  (message "There is either a window above or below the selected window.")
  (message "There is are no windows above or below the selected window."))
```

---

**EDIT** (August 1, 2014):  Based on the updated question of the original poster, the following is an example of how to break the `dolist` loop and throw the result:

```
(defun no-window-is-vertically-split ()
  (catch 'done
    (let* (
        result
        (windows (window-list)))
      (dolist (w windows)
        (when (or
               (window-in-direction 'above w)
               (window-in-direction 'below w))
          (setq result t)
          (throw 'done result))))))
```

Comment: @user4035 -- I'm running out the door now, sorry . . . .  I'll check back in later today if no one has resolved your issue.

Comment: @user4035 -- I modified your proposed function a bit -- when you get a chance, go ahead and see if it meets your needs.  As pointed out by Drew in one of the comments above, this only performs the test on the active frame.

Comment: I am totally ok with checking only the visual frame. Thx!

Answer (score 2):

These two functions will detect horizontal and vertical splits:

```
(defun any-vertical-splits-p ()
  "Return t if any windows have been split vertically."
  (when (member nil (mapcar #'window-full-height-p (window-list))) t))

(defun any-horizontal-splits-p ()
  "Return t if any windows have been split horizontally."
  (when (member nil (mapcar #'window-full-width-p (window-list))) t))
```

I wasn't quite sure I knew what you meant in your diagram.  Vertical and horizontal are used here as Emacs uses them with `split-window-vertically` and `split-window-horizontally`.